# Show only working hours in calendar portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm using Liferay 6.2 GA 4 CE and I want to change the default hours view in the calendar portlet from 24 hours to just working hours (8 am - to 7 pm).

I've looked into the configuration and couldn't find anything related.

How could I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't accomplish your target via portlet configuration, you have to modify the plugin.

The Calendar portlet is an external plugin (it is not a core Liferay portlet) so you can't hook his JSPs, you have to retrieve the source ([source on GitHub](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/6.2.x/portlets/calendar-portlet)), create a project inside your IDE and make the changes you need.